# Android Chrome notifications show up in tray but do not produce a banner

Tags: android, google-chrome, notifications, progressive-web-apps, push

I am building a PWA, but this applies also to all of my chrome notifications produced vai `showNotification`.

The desired behavior would be for a banner to appear for a moment with the notification body, then disappear.

What is happening is I get a notification sound and an icon shows up in the notification tray (this list of little icons at the top) and is in the notifications when I swipe down, but no banner is ever shown.

Here is a simple way I produce notifications:

```
fbsw.showNotification("TITLE",{body:"Body",icon:"/PWA/icon.png",requireInteraction: true});
```

Also I use this in the service worker program

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
var data = event.data.json();
console.log("std push payload",data);
if ("data" in data) {
    data=data.data;
}
event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {body:data.body,icon:data.icon}));
```

});

I have looked through all the options for the showNotifications and tried any that I thought might work, like `requireInteraction` above, without success.

I am not sure if this is an issue with Chrome for Android or the way I am writing the code.  I have tested this on two different phones and the issue is the same.

Answer (score 0):

This question arose from several different issues.

When installed, a PWA on android has its own notification settings, and when notification events are routed through the service worker associated with the application, those notifications follow the rules for that app.

However, it appears that Firebase cloud messaging push messages activate their own version of the service worker that is associated with the chrome app.  So settings need to be modified through that to see the banners.

`chrome>settings>Notifications>sites`

When the option "Pop on screen" is enabled the notifications will produce a banner.

Ideally, I would route my notifications through the PWA, but I haven't figured out how to get it to do that yet.